# How to print Custom Class in For In loop in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, for-in-loop

I have a custom class, as follows in Swift

```
import UIKit

class NewsDealDao: NSObject
{
    var dealID: NSString = ""
    var discountPercent: NSString = ""
    var dealName: NSString = ""
    var dealProvider: NSString = ""
    var descriptionDeal: NSString = ""
    var expiryDate: NSString = ""
    var partnerLevelName: NSString = ""
    var logoPath: NSString = ""
    var categoryName: NSString = ""
    var websiteURL: NSString = ""
    var favourite: NSString = ""
    var distance: NSString = ""

}
```

Now I made its objects, fetched from XML and put inside an Array, i.e news_array.

I want to see values in side Array.

In Objective-C, I could code like

```
for (NewsDealDao *news in news_array){
      NSLog(@"News is %@", news.dealName);
}

While in Swift, I tried, 

for news in news_array {

            println ("\(news)")
        }
```

Also I tried following code, but it crashes,

```
 for var index = 0; index < news_array.count; index++ {

            println("Hello \(index)")


            var news: NewsDealDao = news_array.objectAtIndex(index)

            println("New is \(news.dealName)")


        }




var array_newsDeal = NSMutableArray() //This is how array is made,
//This is protocol
protocol NewsDeal_ParserDelegate {

    func parsingWasFinished(newsDeal_array: NSMutableArray)
}

 //This is adding objects to array, when Tag is called.

 if elementName == "DealDetails" {
            array_newsDeal.addObject(NewsDealDao)
        }

 //Returning array via Protocol to previous class. Where I wana see result.

 func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {

        delegate?.parsingWasFinished(array_newsDeal)

    }
```

Any solution, How can I see variables inside my class objects, which are stored in Array.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the first attempt in swift do wrong and give exception message and stack trace when you see a crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use NSArray,so try this code:

```
var news: NewsDealDao = news_array.objectAtIndex(index) as NewsDealDao
```

In swift,objectAtIndex return AnyObject,you have to convert it to the class type  you want

**Update:**
 I think this line is wrong

```
array_newsDeal.addObject(NewsDealDao)
```

You should add a instance of NewsDealDao,not class

Comment: Crash, Dynamic Cast Class Unconditional is issue. on var news = news_array[index] as NewsDealDao, same crash as above answer.

Comment: I saw it, Thanks, I am adding ClassName, instead of Object, Thanks for giving time.

Comment: array_newsDeal.addObject(NewsDealDao)
 This line had issue, is be object name,with small "N", i.e newsDealDao.

Comment: If this solve your problem,please accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

```
for index in 0...news_array.count
{
    println("Hello \(index)")


        var news = news_array[index] as? NewsDealDao

        println("New is \(news.dealName)")
}
```

Comment: Crash,
Dynamic Cast Class Unconditional is issue. on 
         var news = news_array[index] as NewsDealDao

Comment: see edited Answer! use as? instead as. may be that solve your error as i didn't check its working or not!